# Django popping out data in a serializer returns empty

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I have a problem, this line isn't popping any data despite me passing the data...

```
company_data = validated_data.pop('company', None)
```

Does anyone have any idea why I'm not getting any data passed into my serializer? Thank you everyone ahead of time!
These are parts of my serializer... (The ...... means other parts in between)

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company = CompanySerializer(required=False)
....
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('id', 'email', 'username', 'password', 'first_name',
                                 'name','phone', 'company')
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
....
def create(self, validated_data):
    profile_data = validated_data.pop('user_profile', None)

    company_data = validated_data.pop('company', None)
```

This next part is part of my views....

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def users_list(request):
    """
    List all users or create a new user
    """
    if request.method == 'GET' and request.user.is_superuser:
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            records = User.objects.all()
            serializers = UserSerializer(records, many=True)
            return Response(serializers.data)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        mutable = request.POST._mutable
        request.POST._mutable = True
        request.data["username"] = request.data["email"]
        request.POST._mutable = mutable

        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data) 
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(
            serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST )
.....
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('date_of_subscription', 'company_name', 'address1',
                     'address2', 'city', 'zipcode')
```

Here are my models...

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This line is required. Links UserProfile to a User model instance.
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email_validation_token = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    forgot_password_token = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    rewards = models.ManyToManyField('Reward', through='UserReward')
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="user_profile")

    # Override the __unicode__() method to return out something meaningful!
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Company(models.Model):
    date_of_subscription = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="company",
                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                    primary_key=True)
```

Thanks everyone!

**I know that there is indentation errors (they were from copy/paste, there aren't errors on the site)

Also here is how I am calling it, I tried two ways, one it throws an error if I just pass in a stringified json.

```
var data = new Object();
data.name = name;
data.email = email;
data.password = password;
data.phone = phone;
data.full_name = name;
data.company = {};
data.company.date_of_subscription = output;
data.company.address1 = companyAddress1;
data.company.company_name = companyName;
data.company.address2 = companyAddress2;
data.company.city = companyCity;
data.company.zipcode = companyZipcode;

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'my url',
    data: data,
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (msg) {
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
    }
});
```

I also tried...

```
data.company = {"company_name":"abc", "address1":"abc", "date_of_subscription":"date", "zipcode":"your zipcode", "city":"city name"};
```

It is creating a user and a userprofile but it won't create the company

Comment: Why are you doing this `request.POST._mutable = True;
        request.data["username"] = request.data["email"]` ?

Comment: That is so that I can use the email as a username as well so they don't have both username and email. That part is working though, the mutable is so I can add/change the value of username, I'm unable to without making it mutible (at least as far as I have tried previously)

Comment: IMO you shouldn't be playing around with attributes starting with `_`

Comment: Add the code for the company serializer

Comment: Also from what it looks you have a custom user model, add that too.

Comment: I've added both parts, I will look into a different was as well to remove the mutable. I did remove it for testing and passed a username but the problem was still the same.

Comment: firstly format your code, fix the indentation.

Comment: I've formatted it now with the indentation it should have. I've narrowed it down more, basically there is request.data["company"], but it's not getting passed to the serializer. validated_data contains no company field at all for some reason.

Comment: Found the issue... turns out there was none.
jQuery.ajax function won't take in a javascript object, you need to stringify it first when you use contentType: "application/json".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I never stringified my object. Once I did that it worked perfectly.